# Debugging Rubymine - only debug project files?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, rubymine

I've been using RubyMine and like it a lot so far.

Is there any way to only step through my project files?  When I click "Step Over" or "Step Out" I'm taken into framework and library files, which I don't need to look at.

Answer (score 1):

RubyMine doesn't currently have this feature; [here is the relevant enhancement request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-5291).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know...is there some workaround you guys use, with some combination of the debug fuctions, to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Is this a feature or a bug? Should step over and step out take you into library files? I understand a feature preventing step into from doing that, but step over and step out?