# In Ruby debug, only step through application/project files and skip framework files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-debug, pry

I'm using [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) with [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger). When stepping through the execution stack, I would like to skip over framework and library files and only view code in my project (a rails app).

Is there a way to do this?

[Similar question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732660/debugging-rubymine-only-debug-project-files)

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck with the same question.

Apparently you can exclude the files you don't want to enter by going into `Run|Edit` configurations, then select the code coverage tab and click on the add patterns button.

You have to put in a regular expression for the files you want to exclude.